# java instant double to int

Tags: java, int, double, paint

I have looked around but all conversions have used more than one line and variables. I am trying to paint objects in a certain co-ordinates times a double that changes when you change the size of the frame.

```
Width = getWidth();
Height = getHeight();
cWidth = 1900/Width;
cHeight = 1030/Height;
```

**Inside the paint class,**

```
g.fillOval (PlayerX/cWidth, PlayerY/cHeight, 50/cWidth, 50/cHeight);
```

but I get the error:

**The method fillOval(int, int, int, int) in the type Graphics is not applicable for the arguments (double, double, double, double).**

Would I have to make a separate variable for all 4 for every object painted or is there an easier way?

Comment: Well, you could just cast, e.g. `fillOval((int) PlayerX / cWidth, (int) PlayerY / cHeight,...)`. I'd strongly advise you to start following Java naming conventions, btw.

Comment: `g2d.fill(new Ellipse2D.Double(...))` then you won't need to worry about the `int` converstion, see [`Graphics2D`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html), [`Ellipse2D`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Ellipse2D.html) and [Working with Geometry](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/geometry/index.html) for more details

Comment: @JonSkeet, with all respect Jon, your suggestion will produce an  int/double → double, generating the same compilation issue.... can you verify in my answer :)

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ: Yes, indeed. Still just a cast required, but with extra brackets :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast them to int.

```
g.fillOval ((int)(PlayerX/cWidth), (int)(PlayerY/cHeight), (int)(50/cWidth), (int)(50/cHeight);
```

Answer (score -1):

If your dont have a method like:

```
fillOval(double a, double b, double c, double d)
```

you can not do

```
g.fillOval (PlayerX/cWidth, PlayerY/cHeight, 50/cWidth, 50/cHeight);
```

you need to pass integers not doubles, if loosing the presision is not a problem then try casting

```
g.fillOval ((int)(PlayerX/cWidth), (int)(PlayerY/cHeight), (int)(50/cWidth), (int)(50/cHeight));
```

## Note:

you need to cast carefully grouping the result.
the reason is:

**PlayerX** is a double, same as **cWidth**,
so doing :

```
(int)PlayerX/cWidth
```

will not work, since the result is the same as int/double  → double

---

```
 PlayerX/(int)cWidth
```

will not work either, since the result is the same as doublet/int  → double

---

the option that will work is

```
(int)(PlayerX/cWidth)
```

Comment: it still calls them doubles so the error still comes up

Comment: not possible, double can be cast to int... you have then an error somewhere else...

Comment: i had to cast them